# Optimizing my program by accessing data locally instead of a remote database in C#

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, linq, optimization

I have a database with 4 tables filled with millions of rows. I have my program run on several computers computing data and then returning it to the database. The huge bottleneck in my program design is that for each calculation, it has to download the data and then perform calculations on it and then save the results to the database. When I had the data on the local network it performed with crazy speed so I realize that the resources to download the data from a remote server is the problem.

What are some ways I can save data from the remote database either before or after my code runs so I can make my program more efficient. These calculations are done once and aren't needed again and I have 24 computers running this same program.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            List<StockData> stockData = new List<StockData>();
            List<StockMarketCompare> stockCompareData = new List<StockMarketCompare>();
            List<StockData> sandpInfo = new List<StockData>();
            List<StockData> sandpDateInfo = new List<StockData>();
            List<StockData> globalList = new List<StockData>();
            List<StockData> amexList = new List<StockData>();
            List<StockData> nasdaqList = new List<StockData>();
            List<StockData> nyseList = new List<StockData>();
            List<DateTime> completedDates = new List<DateTime>();
            SymbolInfo symbolClass = new SymbolInfo();
            bool isGoodToGo = false;
            string symbol, market;
            int activeSymbolsCount = 0;
            int rowCount = 0, completedRowCount = 0;
            DateTime date = new DateTime();
            DateTime searchDate = new DateTime();

            // get the data here
            using (StockRatingsTableAdapter stockRatingsAdapter = new StockRatingsTableAdapter())
            using (OoplesDataSet.StockRatingsDataTable stockRatingsTable = new OoplesDataSet.StockRatingsDataTable())
            using (SymbolsTableAdapter symbolAdapter = new SymbolsTableAdapter())
            using (OoplesDataSet.SymbolsDataTable symbolTable = new OoplesDataSet.SymbolsDataTable())
            using (DailyAmexDataTableAdapter dailyAmexAdapter = new DailyAmexDataTableAdapter())
            using (OoplesDataSet.DailyAmexDataDataTable dailyAmexTable = new OoplesDataSet.DailyAmexDataDataTable())
            using (OoplesDataSet.OldStockRatingsDataTable historicalRatingsTable = new OoplesDataSet.OldStockRatingsDataTable())
            using (OldStockRatingsTableAdapter historicalRatingsAdapter = new OldStockRatingsTableAdapter())
            using (OoplesDataSet.OldStockRatingsDataTable historicalRatingSymbolTable = new OoplesDataSet.OldStockRatingsDataTable())
            using (OldStockRatingsTableAdapter historicalRatingSymbolAdapter = new OldStockRatingsTableAdapter())
            using (OoplesDataSet.DailyGlobalDataDataTable sandp500Table = new OoplesDataSet.DailyGlobalDataDataTable())
            using (OoplesDataSet.CurrentSymbolsDataTable currentSymbolTable = new OoplesDataSet.CurrentSymbolsDataTable())
            using (CurrentSymbolsTableAdapter currentSymbolAdapter = new CurrentSymbolsTableAdapter())
            {
                // fill the s&p500 info first
                dailyGlobalAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
                dailyGlobalAdapter.FillBySymbol(sandp500Table, Calculations.sp500);

                var sandpQuery = from c in sandp500Table
                                 select new StockData { Close = c.Close, Date = c.Date, High = c.High, Low = c.Low, Volume = c.Volume };
                sandpInfo = sandpQuery.AsParallel().ToList();

                // set the settings for the historical ratings adapter
                historicalRatingsAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;

                // fill the stock ratings info
                stockRatingsAdapter.Fill(stockRatingsTable);

                // get all symbols in the stock ratings table
                var symbolsAmountQuery = from c in stockRatingsTable
                                         select new SymbolMarket { Symbol = c.Symbol, Market = c.Market };
                List<SymbolMarket> ratingSymbols = symbolsAmountQuery.AsParallel().ToList();

                if (ratingSymbols != null)
                {
                    activeSymbolsCount = ratingSymbols.AsParallel().Count();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < activeSymbolsCount; i++)
                {
                    symbol = ratingSymbols.AsParallel().ElementAtOrDefault(i).Symbol;
                    market = ratingSymbols.AsParallel().ElementAtOrDefault(i).Market;

   dailyAmexAdapter.FillBySymbol(dailyAmexTable, symbol);
                            historicalRatingSymbolAdapter.FillBySymbolMarket(historicalRatingSymbolTable, market, symbol);

                            if (dailyAmexTable != null)
                            {
                                var amexFillQuery = from c in dailyAmexTable
                                                 select new StockData { Close = c.Close, Date = c.Date, High = c.High, Low = c.Low, Volume = c.Volume };
                                amexList = amexFillQuery.AsParallel().ToList();

                                rowCount = amexList.AsParallel().Count();
                            }
                            if (historicalRatingSymbolTable != null)
                            {
                                completedRowCount = historicalRatingSymbolTable.AsParallel().Count();
                                completedDates = historicalRatingSymbolTable.AsParallel().Select(d => d.Date).ToList();
                            }

                    currentSymbolAdapter.Fill(currentSymbolTable);
                    var currentSymbolQuery = from c in currentSymbolTable
                                             where c.Symbol == symbol && c.Market == market
                                             select c;
                    List<OoplesDataSet.CurrentSymbolsRow> currentSymbolRow = currentSymbolQuery.AsParallel().ToList();

                    // if the rows don't match up and if no other computer is working on the same symbol
                    if (rowCount - 30 != completedRowCount && currentSymbolRow.Count == 0)
                    {
                        // update the table to let the other computers know that we are working on this symbol
                        var computerQuery = from c in currentSymbolTable
                                            where c.ComputerName == Environment.MachineName
                                            select c;
                        List<OoplesDataSet.CurrentSymbolsRow> currentComputerRow = computerQuery.AsParallel().ToList();

                        if (currentComputerRow.Count > 0)
                        {
                            // update
                            currentComputerRow.AsParallel().ElementAtOrDefault(0).Symbol = symbol;
                            currentComputerRow.AsParallel().ElementAtOrDefault(0).Market = market;

                            OoplesDataSet.CurrentSymbolsDataTable tempCurrentTable = new OoplesDataSet.CurrentSymbolsDataTable();
                            tempCurrentTable = (OoplesDataSet.CurrentSymbolsDataTable)currentSymbolTable.GetChanges();

                            if (tempCurrentTable != null)
                            {
                                currentSymbolAdapter.Adapter.UpdateCommand.UpdatedRowSource = System.Data.UpdateRowSource.None;
                                currentSymbolAdapter.Update(tempCurrentTable);
                                tempCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();
                                tempCurrentTable.Dispose();
                                Console.WriteLine(Environment.MachineName + " has claimed dominion over " + symbol + " in the " + market + " market!");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // insert
                            currentSymbolAdapter.Insert(symbol, market, Environment.MachineName);
                            Console.WriteLine(Environment.MachineName + " has claimed dominion over " + symbol + " in the " + market + " market!");
                        }

                        Parallel.For(0, rowCount - 30, new ParallelOptions
                            {
                                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
                            }, j =>
                            {
                                        if (amexList.AsParallel().Count() > 0)
                                        {
                                            date = amexList.AsParallel().ElementAtOrDefault(j).Date;
                                            searchDate = date.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(60));

                                            if (completedDates.Contains(date) == false)
                                            {
                                                var amexQuery = from c in sandpInfo
                                                                where c.Date >= searchDate && c.Date <= date
                                                                join d in amexList on c.Date equals d.Date
                                                                select new StockMarketCompare { stockClose = d.Close, marketClose = c.Close };

                                                var amexStockDataQuery = from c in amexList
                                                                            where c.Date >= searchDate && c.Date <= date
                                                                            select new StockData { Close = c.Close, High = c.High, Low = c.Low, Volume = c.Volume, Date = c.Date };

                                                stockCompareData = amexQuery.AsParallel().ToList();
                                                stockData = amexStockDataQuery.AsParallel().ToList();
                                                isGoodToGo = true;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                isGoodToGo = false;
                                            }
                                        }

                                if (completedDates.Contains(date) == false)
                                {
                                    var sandpDateQuery = from c in sandpInfo
                                                        where c.Date >= searchDate && c.Date <= date
                                                        select c;
                                    sandpDateInfo = sandpDateQuery.AsParallel().ToList();
                                    symbolClass = new SymbolInfo(symbol, market);
                                    isGoodToGo = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    isGoodToGo = false;
                                }

                                if (isGoodToGo)
                                {
                                    sendMessage(sandpInfo, date, symbolClass, stockData, stockCompareData);
                                }
                            });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but why are you doing this work on remote computers in the first place? Can't you just let the database engine do all the work?

Comment: @Luaan the calculations I need to do on the data can't be done using sql statements so I need to run them on the computers instead

Comment: Why do you think they can't be done using sql statements?  T-SQL is a turing complete language, and therefore you can do pretty much anything in it.  Even if what you want to do is *easier* in a different language, there's sqlclr that lets you run .NET code directly in the database.  There's also sql extended stored procedures.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch My apologies as I'm not familiar with either of those technologies. Would you happen to have any good links for someone brand new to those languages?

Comment: Well, is your server in your control?  Or is it hosted by a third party?  If it's a third party, they probably won't allow a lot of things.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Yes it is hosted by a third party but it is a dedicated server which I have control over everything as far as I know

Comment: If you have administrative control over the sql server, then you should be good... First, I don't typically recommend sqlclr as it can cause performance issues if used incorrectly.  And it's really splitting your code between two different domains.   However, here's a starter http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/sql-clr-for-beginner-part-1-create-store-procedure-in-sql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be doing is overkill and will not bring you that far.

On a first glance I spot couple of lines that I suspect of the N+1 syndrome.

The massive use of AsParallel to create a list or even count won't bring any benefits either.

What worries me most however, you're talking about 4 tables but I count 13 Adapters?

Almost obvious that you are doing all the work client side.

Instead of blindly filling datasets with full table contents and then filter on the result: craft a queries with the data you need without omitting a WHERE clause. Now all your [24 computers] are plowing through the same mess.

And as mentioned in the comments above, you'll be amazed how much you can do with T-SQL.

Preprocess that data server-side; merge, join & filter and perhaps aggregate the results into a 5-th (temp) table.

Let you other computers query against those results with partioning in mind so they all take about 1/24th part of the work.

That is not using AsParallel but being Parallel. Way more efficient, less trouble some and way clearer

Bottom line: Redesign :-)